# How to call toString method from another toString method?

Tags: java, methods, tostring

I have three classes in this hierarchy : Bank-Account-Client.
In Bank class I created an ArrayList of Accounts and when I create some, I wanna write a method to print them. I know I must override toString method in Account and Client class. Overriding toString method in Client class is easy but in Account class I have no idea how can I call toString method from Client class. I tried something like this but it doesn't give me expected results. I would be grateful for any advice here. Thanks.

```
//toString method from Account class

 public String toString(){
   Client temp=new Client();
   return temp.toString();
 }

//toString method from Client class

  public String toString(){
    return firstName+" "+lastName+" "+address+" "+pin;
  }
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Comment: `super.toString();`

Comment: is it really a hierarchy? the classes extend each other?

Comment: You really shouldn't have a hierarchy here. An account **isn't** also a client. You should be using composition

Comment: In Client class I only create Client object with name, surname etc, then it goes to Account class where I can do some operations like deposit charge etc, and after that in main Bank class I create arraylist of Accounts- what is wrong with this design?

Comment: Please show more of your classes (such as member variables). Does the Account class have a reference to a Client? If so, your account `toString()` can call `client.toString()`.